# How can I get the number of affected columns after updating an entity?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to implement item versioning using EF, and what I need to know is whether or not the entity which I called `Update()` on actually got changed, so I can increment its version number. How can I obtain this information?

My repository `Update` function looks like this:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
  dbset.Attach(entity);
  dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information from the entity state.

If a property has been changed, the state will be "Modified" otherwise "Unchanged".

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    var first =  ctx.Entity_Basics.First();
    var x1 = ctx.IsModified(first); // false
    first.ColumnInt = 9999;
    var x2 = ctx.IsModified(first); // true
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsModified <T>(this DbContext context, T entity) where T : class
    {
        return context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was looking for something built-in into EF, but I had to opt for the workaround you can see in my answer.

Comment: Here for you an extension methods which is way better for performance than retrieving data from database then serializing the object. I will add this method later this week to my EF+ library.

Answer (score 0):

What I opted for afterall was comparing the serialized versions of the 2:

```
public void UpdateProduct(Product product)
{
    var productInDb = GetByID(product.Id);
    if (!JToken.DeepEquals(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productInDb)))
        product.CurrentVersion++;
    product = Update(product);
}
```